# How to use "Pull Request Query"?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to return a pull request based on a commit. I found this > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20query/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

> This API is used to find what pull requests are related to a given commit.

I'm using the following code:

```
$body = @"
{
    "items": [
        {
            "59c1c31397b266116ff6d735e5638ef5d1b598a0"
        }
    ]
}
"@ 

$someLink = "https://dev.something.com/embrace/somethingSomething/_apis/git/repositories/****-bf64-47d9-8b10-53f21220d54d/pullrequestquery?api-version=5.1"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $someLink -Headers @{Authorization = $pat } -Body $body -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json'
```

When I run the release I get a:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: I believe it's related to the token you're using in the authorization header. Can you share what you're trying?

Comment: It's not the authorization. 400 bad request has something to do with a bad input of data. How do you mean share what I'm trying? I'm trying to return a pull request based on a commit id.

Comment: I know. I've reviewed your request based on the link and it seems to be ok. The only part that is not included in the question is the security (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20query/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#security), this is why I've thought it could be the problem.

Comment: I'm 99% sure the issue is the json body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the following body:

```
$body = @"
{
    "queries": [{
        "items": [
            "59c1c31397b266116ff6d735e5638ef5d1b598a0"
        ],
        "type": "commit"
    }]
}
"@
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Don't the values in the items array need a propertie? //edit Getting a 404. Which is a lot better then a 400. I'm gonna double check all other values.

Comment: seems to be only string array according to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20query/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#gitpullrequestqueryinput

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio the request works for me, but the Azure DevOps Server response a `Body` that is exactly like my input: `{"queries":[{"type":"commit","items":["c8046fcec9c52122e49719f83b224f8dc7cc1bf2"]}],"results":[{}]}`

Comment: Found out: passed commit ID was from an active PR and not part of `master`. Commit IDs from completed PR works!

Comment: Use a `"type": "lastMergeCommit"` to get a commit not merged with `master`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Powershell doesn't seem to like arrays unless they are wrapped in @().

```
$body = @{
  queries = @(
    @{
      items = @(
        "59c1c31397b266116ff6d735e5638ef5d1b598a0"
      )
      type = "commit"
    }
  )
}
```